# Is there a way to see how my file was edited - node.JS

Tags: node.js, file, chokidar

I have a file and I am reading it through `chokidar`. I am also writing to the same file in some another function using `fs.writeFileSync`.
I want to emit the watcher.on('change') function only when the file is changed manually (i.e. not through WriteFileSync). Is there a way of determining that ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, not to my knowledge.

You can only know the file was changed, not what process/... changed it.